# Accessing member variables with a pointer to a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, data-structures, member-variables

I'm having some trouble here, using C++ regarding access to a member variable via a pointer.

Say I have the following class, and it has some output and a unique tag.

```
class CSource
{
   public:
   int tag;
   double output;
}
```

I want to store a pointer to the class and the tag in a struct like this

```
struct foo
{
    CSource *source;
    int sourceTag;
}
```

Then in a second class, have a member function that takes a pointer to the CSource class as an argument

```
class CDest
{
    public:
    void addSource(CSource *sourcePtr);
}
```

And that member function stores the pointer and tag into a struct

```
void CDest::addSource(CSource *sourcePtr)
{
    foo temp;
    foo.source = sourcePtr;
    foo.tag-> sourcePtr.tag; 
}
```

The last line gives me the error "error: expression must have pointer type." I just want the raw tag value and not a pointer, because the next step is to search through a list to see if that source has already been added or not, add it, and then have an inverse function that searches the list and removes the struct if it's there using the tag.

Comment: It's impossible to have a pointer to a class in C++, you can however have a pointer to an instance of a class.

Answer (score 2):

You shall use variable name, not class name:

```
foo temp;
temp.source = sourcePtr;
temp.tag = sourcePtr->tag;
```

Comment: `foo` has no member named `tag` and I don't see any attempt to use a type name as a variable.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious and what is this `foo temp;  foo.source = sourcePtr;`you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try this "foo.tag = sourcePtr->tag" instead of "foo.tag->sourcePtr.tag".

You will not get compilation error after that.

By the way, if your motive is to insert the "CSource" object uniquely, you can use std::set instead of using linked list.